# Call plpgsql Function from a PL/Python Function in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

Is is possible to call a `plpgsql function` (or any `PostgreSQL function`) from a `PL/Python` function?

So, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    ...
BEGIN
    ...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then use it here

```
CREATE FUNCTION pythonFunc() RETURNS void AS $$
    ...
    someFunc() #postgreSQL function
    ...
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
create function plpython_function()
returns void as $$

    plpy.execute('select plpgsql_function()')

$$ language plpythonu;
```

[PL/Python Database Access](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html)

Comment: How would you pass arguments on from the plpython_function to the plpgsql_function? The short answer to this would be, "import plpy and use plpy.quote_literal". My reply to that would be, "that's all very well, but 8.2 (actually, Greenplum) does not have plpy.quote_literal, it is actually quote_literal that I want to call!" Bootstrap problem.